# How do I repeat span styling multiple times?

Tags: html, css

I want to colour different words from a same line. Doing it with span style will take so much hassle if I repeat such lines. Is there an easier way? 
For example: "The sun is up." Suppose I want 'the', 'sun' and 'up' to be coloured red, green and blue. And if I repeat such styling, it will become a hectic job. Any easier way ? I'm learning css.

Comment: Your question is not very clear. [CSS selectors](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp)

Comment: @Ihazkode I want to write few lines in css declaration format. Just like I wrote in the question. It's not the actual code, but written as plain text. Now imagine if I want to colour the differents parts of a same line. I need to use span right?
Like <span style="color: blue;">selector</span> {<span style="color: red;">property</span>: <span style="color: green;">value</span>;}
Got it now? But doing this many times is hectic. Is there any other way?

Comment: What's your actual issue? Why can't you use a class and use it in the selector? `<span class="something">foo</span>`

Comment: It seems like you have 0 research effort.

Comment: @OmriLuzon yeah let me use another example. Suppose there is a sentence "the sun is up". If I want to colour "the", "sun" and "up" all three of them differently, I need to use an inline span style no? But doing that for many lines would be so hectic. What is the easier way?

Comment: You need to wrap each element in a `span` and use `nth-child`

Comment: Can you put a legitimate use-case in the question?

Comment: @Ihazkode please show me an example. I'm in learning phase. I know about nth child but don't understand how it will work in this situation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make use of [nth-child](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_nth-child.asp) selector.

You still need to **wrap your words** in separate `spans` but this is how I would target different words in a sentence as a template.

```css
.foo span:nth-child(1) {
  color: red
}

.foo span:nth-child(2) {
  color: blue
}

.foo span:nth-child(3) {
  color: green
}
```

```html
<div class="foo">
  <span>selector 1</span> <span>property 1</span>: <span>value 1</span>
</div>

<div class="foo">
  <span>selector 2</span> <span>property 2</span>: <span>value 2</span>
</div>

<div class="foo">
  <span>selector 3</span> <span>property 3</span>: <span>value 3</span>
</div>

<div class="foo">
  <span>selector 4</span> <span>property 4</span>: <span>value 4</span>
</div>
```

Comment: Wow. This is much easier. Thank you very much. You have been very helpful. Sometimes it's not easy to form the question in proper way but thank you for your patience, understanding and the quick help.

Comment: @SMalakar No problem, happy to help. Good luck and thank you.